# Is there ever any need for multiple Box2D worlds?

Tags: box2d

Are there any scenarios where more than one Box2D worlds are needed in one app scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do some very creative stuff with multiple Box2D worlds, but as a rule, you will only ever need one.

Comment: Physics should be simulated in layers, with only relevant scales interacting with each other.

Comment: @Misha: That would be terribly inefficient. You'd have to code a whole new chunk of code to handle layer interactions. Where would be the advantage of that?

Answer (score 2):

You use multiple worlds for noninteracting physics regions and for simulating microscale verse macro scale interactions. Different time steps of motion come to mind and there are advantages to isolating noninteracting regions.